# Unset mysql_fetch_field object value MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, object, unset

I have a code like this

I have a stored procedure which will fetch all the info.
But I want in my php view part to display only selected fields. How can I achieve that.
Say for ex: the below code has three fields in db. S.No - BookName - Author Name
If I want to unset a field value i.e. S.No  - How can I do that

I have tried the unset function like this. But dnt work
unset($res->name->s_no);

## Code

```
    <?php 
    $pa_query = mysql_query("call booklist()"); 
    while($i<mysql_num_fields($pa_query)){
    $res=mysql_fetch_field($pa_query,$i);
    ?>
    <th><?php echo $res->name; ?></th>
    <?php $i=$i+1;  
    }
    ?>
```

## Output

```
    S.No        Book Name       Author Name
```

## Expected Output

```
    Book Name        Author Name
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to unset the property s_no of the property name of the object $res. Mysql_fetch_field is bringing back a single columns details as an object so on its first call $res->name is s_no, rather s_no being a property of $res->name. As you only seem to want the names I think I would just use mysql_fetch_assoc() or the like, and unset the first column of the returned array, then using the others for the output.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first please use the `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

The best way will be : `select the only required column` in query as:

```
select Book Name Author Name from book_master // there wont be any space in the column name
```

OR

simply `use if condition` as:

```
  if($res->name!='S.No'){?> 
      <th><?php echo $res->name; ?></th>
  <?php }?>
```

Hope this will  help!

Comment: Please check my question again
I have a stored procedure which will fetch all the info.
But I want in my php view part to display only selected fields. How can I achieve that.

Comment: @user3350885 I believe the or part will achieve the same!

Comment: ur code works, but stil i have a empty cell in the header part. i.e the cell space for S.No (only the S.No is not visible but the cell is taken by the table)

Comment: @user3350885 how come? the if condition is before creating the cell if the column is 'S.No' on cell will be created!